# Launching an APP from volume ID

Tags: c, winapi, shellexecute

I'm trying to launch an `.exe` file in windows using and a volume ID. The volume do not have a letter. Here is what I've tryed.

### ShellExecute

When I call `ShellExecute` with the volume ID, Windows' explorer open the correct directory. Same thing if I try to open a folder inside the volume. However, if I try to open an exe file, nothing happen.

This is the way I call ShellExecute, which is part of `windows.h` :

```
char path[MAX_PATH] = R"(\\?\Volume{0dc7f9cc-d3ea-11e4-824b-806e6f6e6963}\App.exe)";    
LONG_PTR returnValue = (LONG_PTR) ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(),NULL, path,NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW);
```

The error code returned is 2 :

> The system cannot find the file specified.

### CreateProcessW

After following the comments, I am now using . My new code look like this :

```
char path[MAX_PATH] = R"(\\?\Volume{0dc7f9cc-d3ea-11e4-824b-806e6f6e6963}\launcher.exe)";

STARTUPINFO info = {sizeof(info)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
if (CreateProcessW(path, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
else {
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    printf("ERROR CODE: %d", dw);
}
```

But it still doesn't work. Error is the same (2).

### Changing the path notation

From `"\\?\Volume{ID}"` to `"\\.\Volume{ID}"`.
The strange thing is that **I can list the drive's files or start a console process but I cannot launch any GUI EXE files**. Error code remains 2.

*Is the anythink I am missing here ? Any help are welcome. Thank you.*

---

### Answer

I've got confuse with the comments, using `"\\.\Volume{ID}\myApp.exe"` worked well if used with CreateProcess, not CreateProcessW.

There is the fully functional code (Don't forget to include `windows.h`).

```
char path[MAX_PATH] = R"(\\.\Volume{0dc7f9cc-d3ea-11e4-824b-806e6f6e6963}\App.exe)";

STARTUPINFO info = {sizeof(info)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
if (CreateProcess(path, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
{
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
else 
{
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    printf("ERROR CODE WHILE STARTING: %d", dw);
}
```

Comment: Where is your [MCVE]?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Remove the unrelated tag when you post the [mcve].

Comment: Actualy, this line remains the same in both C and C++. I thought this was the mnimal complete, the only thing missing should be "#include <windows.h>" and the value of "path" witch is my VolumeId, which is different on every computer. I will edit my post to complete the informations.

Comment: There are no raw string literals in C, so the code doesn't even compile as C. Besides, it's time to stop using `ShellExecute`, because it doesn't properly report errors. Use `ShellExecuteEx` instead. And make sure to initialize COM on the calling thread, as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx).

Comment: There is in C11, the code compile on my computer. As I said, if I remove "App.exe" from "path", it work and open the folder in explorer. I will have a look at ShellExecuteEx. TY.

Comment: [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx): *"If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx)."*

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, thank you. I did that actually as I 've said in the POST. Error code is 2. That correspond to _The system cannot find the file specified_

Comment: Nothing in your question indicates what the return value of `GetLastError` is in case `CreateProcess` fails.

Comment: You could try to run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to find out, which file cannot be found. If there is a difference between console and GUI applications, it's likely, that it's a dependency, that cannot be resolved. (Although I'm not sure that'd generate error code 2.)

Answer (score 1):

problem in win32 subsystem - it not use native for windows [NT Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#nt_namespaces), but [Win32 Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#win32_file_namespaces) which first must be converted to [NT Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#nt_namespaces) before passing to kernel.

also some functions, like `ShellExecuteEx` or `CreateProcessW` accept not any **valid** win32 path, but only restricted subset - so called *Drive Letter* form. if pass path in form `\\?\Volume{guid}\*` - `ShellExecuteEx` and `CreateProcessW` always fail with this path (so called volume path) even if path correct (`CreateFileW` open this path). funny that `CreateProcessW` will be work with path `\\.\Volume{guid}\*` (if replace `?` to `.` at `[2]` position) but `ShellExecuteEx` not worked with this path too.

only one reliable solution here - convert this volume form path to *Drive Letter* form. this can be done with help [`IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560474(v=vs.85).aspx) - need get list of all [`MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562286(v=vs.85).aspx) in system and do 2 loops by this list - first found device name by existing volume symlink. then in loop #2 - by already known device name found - dos-device name and got it drive letter

```
#include <mountmgr.h>

ULONG NtVolumePathToDosPath(PUNICODE_STRING VolumePath)
{
    if (!MOUNTMGR_IS_NT_VOLUME_NAME(VolumePath))
    {
        return ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    static volatile UCHAR guz;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x400;

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PMOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINTS pmmp;
    };

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(MOUNTMGR_DOS_DEVICE_NAME, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    static MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT mmp;

    ULONG dwError = NOERROR;
    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb) cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);

        if (!DeviceIoControl(hFile, IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS, &mmp, sizeof(mmp), buf, cb, &rcb, 0))
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
            rcb = pmmp->Size;
            continue;
        }

        dwError = ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND;

        if (ULONG NumberOfMountPoints = pmmp->NumberOfMountPoints)
        {
            PMOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT MountPoints = pmmp->MountPoints;

            //loop #1: search for DeviceName linked to VolumePath
            do 
            {
                UNICODE_STRING SymbolicLinkName = {
                    MountPoints->SymbolicLinkNameLength,
                    SymbolicLinkName.Length,
                    (PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(pmmp, MountPoints->SymbolicLinkNameOffset)
                };

                if (MOUNTMGR_IS_VOLUME_NAME(&SymbolicLinkName))
                {
                    if (RtlEqualUnicodeString(&SymbolicLinkName, VolumePath, TRUE))
                    {
                        // found DeviceName
                        UNICODE_STRING _DeviceName = {
                            MountPoints->DeviceNameLength,
                            _DeviceName.Length,
                            (PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(pmmp, MountPoints->DeviceNameOffset)
                        };

                        NumberOfMountPoints = pmmp->NumberOfMountPoints;
                        MountPoints = pmmp->MountPoints;

                        // loop #2: search for "drive letter" linked to DeviceName
                        do 
                        {
                            UNICODE_STRING DeviceName = {
                                MountPoints->DeviceNameLength,
                                DeviceName.Length,
                                (PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(pmmp, MountPoints->DeviceNameOffset)
                            };

                            if (RtlEqualUnicodeString(&_DeviceName, &DeviceName, FALSE))
                            {
                                SymbolicLinkName.MaximumLength = SymbolicLinkName.Length = MountPoints->SymbolicLinkNameLength;
                                SymbolicLinkName.Buffer = (PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(pmmp, MountPoints->SymbolicLinkNameOffset);

                                if (MOUNTMGR_IS_DRIVE_LETTER(&SymbolicLinkName))
                                {
                                    PWSTR szVolumePath = VolumePath->Buffer + 48;
                                    *--szVolumePath = ':';
                                    *--szVolumePath = SymbolicLinkName.Buffer[12];
                                    *--szVolumePath = '\\';
                                    *--szVolumePath = '?';
                                    *--szVolumePath = '\\';
                                    *--szVolumePath = '\\';
                                    VolumePath->Buffer = szVolumePath;
                                    dwError = NOERROR;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        } while (MountPoints++, --NumberOfMountPoints);

                        break;
                    }
                }

            } while (MountPoints++, --NumberOfMountPoints);
        }
        break;

    } while (dwError == ERROR_MORE_DATA);

    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return dwError;
}

ULONG TestExecByVolumePath(PCWSTR szVolumePath)
{
    size_t size = wcslen(szVolumePath) * sizeof(WCHAR);

    if (size >= MAXUSHORT || size < 98)
    {
        return ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    UNICODE_STRING VolumePath;

    VolumePath.Length = 96;
    VolumePath.MaximumLength = (USHORT)size + sizeof(WCHAR);
    memcpy(VolumePath.Buffer = (PWSTR)alloca(VolumePath.MaximumLength), szVolumePath, VolumePath.MaximumLength);

    if (!MOUNTMGR_IS_DOS_VOLUME_NAME(&VolumePath))
    {
        return ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    VolumePath.Buffer[1] = '?';

    ULONG dwErr = NtVolumePathToDosPath(&VolumePath);

    if (dwErr == NOERROR)
    {
        SHELLEXECUTEINFOW sei = {sizeof(sei), 0, 0, L"open", VolumePath.Buffer, 0, 0, SW_SHOWDEFAULT };
        if (!ShellExecuteExW(&sei))
        {
            dwErr = GetLastError();
        }
    }

    return dwErr;
}

    TestExecByVolumePath(L"\\\\?\\Volume{***}\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
```

Comment: `PVOID stack = alloca(guz);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable - not agree. i many years use this in very different code (in kernel mode too) and ensure that this correct worked. compiler (ok *CL* - i use only it) exactly return to  us pointer to current stack. call `PVOID stack = alloca(0);` - this is really *UB* because with optimization i note CL simply drop call `alloca(0);` and `stack` became undefined. but the **volatile** keyword make self task - with this the `alloca` is always called (checked on all *CL* from 2005 vs up to latest builds) however this not related to question.

Comment: if you not like this style (and look like only i do this kind of codding for cumulative alloca (need off RT checks for this)  on loop) you can use new/delete malloc/free or what ever else here. this is already another question

Comment: @IInspectable - and from *MSDN* - [*If size is 0, _alloca allocates a zero-length item and returns a valid pointer to that item.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx) - this is exactly what i need **valid pointer** to zero-length item *stack*. *stack* is not storage, but mark, by which i calculated actual buffer size *buf* - `RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);` - so what you men under *UB* here ? direct call `alloca(0)` - this is *UB* because how i note *CL* with optimization simply drop this instruction at all !

Comment: and `alloca(guz)` will drop if `guz` declared without *volatile*. but when we declare it as **volatile** all is fine

Comment: Sorry, `guz` looked like an uninitialized variable, but isn't (at least in C99, not sure about C89). Besides that you don't appear to understand what undefined behavior is.

Comment: @IInspectable - think understand what you mean. i not direct init `guz` to 0. however i use indirect zero init - `static`

Comment: [*When you declare a variable, the variable has static duration and the compiler initializes it to 0 unless you specify another value.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Hi, first off all thank you for your time and answere me. The problem is a bit deeper. In fact, I'm trying to access to a drive that do not have any Drive Letter assigned.

Comment: In fact, I can launch a console app using the _Volume Path_ and `CreateProcess` but with the exact same code, I cannot launch any GUI app.

Comment: @Jean-CharbelVANNIER - `I'm trying to access to a drive` this is possible, but without  `ShellExecuteExW` - it will ne not worked. file functions - at all no any problems. if need process exec - use `CreateProcess` only and `"\\\\.\\"`prefix. you even can use Nt-path by *`"\\\\.\\globalroot\\device\\hardiskvolumeX\\.."`* - about GUI or console - this is absolute not important here. say for notepad this is 100% worked

Comment: @Jean-CharbelVANNIER - this code fine work - `STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(si)};
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  if (CreateProcessW(L"\\\\.\\globalroot\\systemroot\\notepad.exe", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, &si, &pi))
  {
   CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
   CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  }`

Comment: @Jean-CharbelVANNIER - `drive that do not have any Drive Letter assigned.` and as variant you can easy assign some free letter to this drive yourself by call `DefineDosDevice` or `ZwCreateSymbolicLinkObject` and use it

Comment: I am trully sorry but the code provided doesn't work either. Error cod is still 2.

Comment: strange, i test this code on all systems from xp to win10 (both x64 and x86) and it nice worked. you exactly copied string ? `L"\\\\.\\globalroot\\systemroot\\notepad.exe‌​"` ? "notepad.exe" exist in your system ? if call `CreateFile` with this path ? what will be result ?

Comment: @Jean-CharbelVANNIER - `CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\globalroot\\systemroot\\notepad.exe", 0,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);` must open file,if system not damaged

Comment: @RbMm Notepad.exe do exist in my system. I am not trying to run the code in your answere, but the one in your comment. I've tested in 3 different computer without success. So I've tryed to create the process in C# with this exact path "\\\\.\\globalroot\\systemroot\\notepad.exe‌". The error message tell me that it cannot access to network drive. Also, I must say that when I use the "\\\.\\Volume{ID}" notation, I can perform many operation like listing the directory content but I can't run the exe file.

Comment: `I've tested in 3 different computer without success.` - strange, because in all my test `CreateProcessW(L"\\\\.\\globalroot\\systemroot\\notepad.exe‌​", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, &si, &pi)` working..

Comment: @Jean-CharbelVANNIER - if you call CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\globalroot\\systemroot\\notepad.exe", 0,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0); this is worked ? and may be in string task (c#) ? may be not convert \\ to single \ ?

Comment: exactly string must be `\\.\globalroot\systemroot\notepad.exe‌‌` - any way - what result of CreateFile (OPEN_EXISTING) on this path ?

Comment: @Jean-CharbelVANNIER - you absolute mistake. that cmd.exe can call `CreateProcessW` ok - only prove that - some error in your code. cmd.exe not doing any magic stuff. in simply take string as is and call `CreateProcess` - if in `cmd.exe` - this must be and ok in your - **if no mistakes**

Comment: @Jean-CharbelVANNIER - `By default, CreateProcess on windows uses cmd.exe` - absolute false

Comment: @Jean-CharbelVANNIER - again simply run cmd.exe and execute `\\.\globalroot\systemroot\notepad.exe‌‌` command. this will be work or no ? if yes - **error in how you** call `CreateProcessW`. `\.\Volume{guid}\myApp.exe` as cmd parameter worked for me - but and `CreateProcessW` work with this !! cmd.exe and call `CreateProcessW` with same line.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I've got confuse with {system()}. Anyway, replacing CreateProcessW by CreateProcess worked when using dot instead of question mark.

Comment: @Jean-CharbelVANNIER - i wrote about this you in anser at very begin `"funny that CreateProcessW will be work with path \\.\Volume{guid}\* (if replace ? to . at [2] position) but ShellExecuteEx not worked with this path too. "` and what you mean under `replacing CreateProcessW by CreateProcess` ?

Comment: Exactly the oposite. It doesn't work with CreateProcessW but only with CreateProcess.

Comment: @Jean-CharbelVANNIER - you again mistake!! at first not exist function `CreateProcess` - exist `CreateProcessA` and `CreateProcessW`. what i wrote of course worked with both `A` and `W` versions. and use `W` of course much more better -`A` must not be used. you make some mistake. may be pass const commant line to W

Comment: @Jean-CharbelVANNIER - so do **so many** mistakes. permanent - mistake by mistake